# Cookie expiry date is taking session value in magento

Tags: magento, cookies, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I want to set session timeout limit for one of the store views in my magento site, 
Done too much R&D by surfing several sites, but doesn't come up with any solution

Here is the explanation:

My cookie settings ib admin panel for default config

```
System->Configuration->Web->Session Cookie management

Cookie Lifetime  900
Cookie Path      /
Cookie Domain   (blank)
Use HTTP Only    yes
```

And my store view settings

```
Cookie Lifetime  120
Cookie Path      /
Cookie Domain   (blank)
Use HTTP Only    yes

adminhtml iub2qjrvtcvv46rutus50gngo6 mydomain.com  /  Session  35
frontend  573ofasrb0l7ems6kr5nv1mo01 mydomain.com  /  Session  34
frontend  573ofasrb0l7ems6kr5nv1mo01 .mydomain.com /  Wed, 03 Sep 2014 09:23:40 GMT 34
```

Is there any wrong in my settings and why the cookie expiry date is taking as "session" and the cookie is not expiring in 120 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I find out the solution. In magento cookies time always set in second, you need to convert your date or time to seconds then you will set your cookies in magento according to you.

```
// Cookies set for one month in magento:
$expire = strtotime(date("m/d/Y, H:i:s A", time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30));
$cookies = Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('name', 'value', 'expire');
```

**Output**: 09/13/2015, 10:43:39 AM (calculate with current date).